# selenium web driver and webpagetest.org .HAR files differences

Tags: java, selenium

I have generated .HAR files using Selenium Web Driver with BrowserMob Proxy(SWD+BM) and by using webpagetest.org(WPT). I used HAR Storage to view these files. The following are the differences I found.

a.  All the sizes and times(Load Time, DNS Time, Transfer Time etc.) shown in SWD+BM are less compared to WPT.

b.  No. of resources by request(images, css, html etc. ), resources  by size, domains by request, domains by size  in SWD+BM are less in number or equal to(mostly less) when compared to WPT.

I have used Firefox browser for the both.

Why are these differences? Is there any architecture difference b/w these two?

Comment: I had similar questions earlier, which I had posted.  Here's the link to that if it helps..  https://groups.google.com/group/browsermob-proxy/browse_thread/thread/62ae3da3781fff68#.

Comment: Thanks Niharika, got some doubts cleared on BrowserMob Proxy. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

WPT by default simulates low bandwidth DSL connections. BMP does support traffic shaping, but not by default.

The difference in requests is likely just due to timing issues and dynamic elements on the page.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the Clarification. All my doubts got clearned now.                           


@All: I have posted my doubts in other forums. Please find the links below. There is some more information here.

http://www.webpagetest.org/forums/showthread.php?tid=11206&pid=17697#pid17697

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/browsermob-proxy/lwkOW0toNu4